# Обновил Gitlab и получил ошибку

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Добрый день.
Обновил Gitlab до версии 10.3.4

Gitlab находится за Nginx.

Получаю вот такую ошибку в файле `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
App 13420 stdout: 
[ N 2018-01-18 22:22:22.1062 4233/T5 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:994 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 13420, application /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
App 14688 stdout: 
App 14688 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (git) and Ruby interpreter...
App 14688 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 14688 stderr:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 14688 stderr:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-oadyo.log
App 14688 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 14688 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 14688 stderr:      # tar xzf rubyext-ruby-2.3.5-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
App 14688 stderr:      # rm -f rubyext-ruby-2.3.5-x86_64-linux.tar.gz
App 14688 stderr:      Checking whether downloaded binary is usable...
App 14688 stderr:      # /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby -I. test.rb
App 14688 stderr:      Binary is usable.
App 14688 stderr:      # current user is: git
App 14688 stderr:      # mkdir -p /var/opt/gitlab/.passenger/native_support/5.1.12/ruby-2.3.5-x86_64-linux
App 14688 stderr:      Encountered permission error, but no more directories to try. Giving up.
App 14688 stderr:      -------------------------------
App 14688 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 14688 stderr:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
```

Кто-то сталкивался с этим?
Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1727

Comment: дал права пользователю git на папку /var/opt/gitlab/.passenger/ и всё получилось. Спасибо.